# Overcoming interface limitations in complex design in Go

Tags: go

I want to set an interface that enforces the following behavior. Structs that implement the Rules interface, implement a prepareData() function, they contain Conditions that Evaluate() the prepared data, and return a result. If the data passes all conditions, actions can be triggered.

There may be different structs that implement this Rules interface e.g. a JSONRules object as in the example below, where the prepared data are in JSON format, and a JSON Condition that simply checks for a value of a field in the JSON object. Or it could be something completely different e.g. GET a URL and check if it is reachable with HTTP status is 200.

There's 3 objectives in the design:

1. The main program should be agnostic to the implementation e.g. whether it's JSONRules or a URLRules that it's executing. It should simply be able to say Do(Rules) e.g. do what you have to do and let me know the result.
2. The sequence of execution e.g. prepareData(), evaluateConditions() should be abstracted since it is the same for all Rules and we shouldn't have to write it all over again.
3. As part of the sequence of execution, actions will be triggered via a separate, specialized component which could be an external API, which is one more reason that this part should be abstracted and not re-implemented by each individual rules.

Below is an example of how I went about implementing this. The problem that I face is that the Data and the way the data are evaluated by each Condition are different for every implementation, which means that the Condition interface cannot be aware of certain fields or functions, but yet, the implementations need to follow the interfaces. I therefore get a "data.actualValue undefined (type Data is interface with no methods)" error in the following example.

The code should speak for itself, if I'm not explaining this well. Are there are any design pattern in Go that would help overcoming the limitations in interfaces in Go?

Here is a link to the code at the Go Playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/G9XnEZ74bM

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  condition := JSONCondition{ "Expected Value" }
  rules := JSONRules{
    RulesBase{
      data : nil,
      conditions : []Condition{ condition },
    },
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  Do(rules)
}

type Rules interface {
  getData() Data
  getConditions() []Condition
  prepareData()
  evaluateConditions() bool
}

type RulesBase struct {
  data         Data
  conditions []Condition
}

func (rules RulesBase) getData() Data {
  return rules.data
}

func (rules RulesBase) getConditions() []Condition {
  return rules.conditions
}

func (rules RulesBase) evaluateConditions() bool {
  allOk := true
  for _, condition := range rules.getConditions() {
    ok := condition.Evaluate(rules.getData())
    if !ok {
      allOk = false
      break
    }
  }  

  return allOk
}

func Do(rules Rules) {
  rules.prepareData()
  ok := rules.evaluateConditions()

  if ok {
    // Take some actions if the conditions evaluated successfully.                                                                                                                                                                           
    fmt.Println("Conditions passed.")
  }
}

type Data interface {}

type Condition interface {
  Evaluate(Data) bool
}

type JSONRules struct {
  RulesBase
  // Could have additional fields that would be used to prepare the data such as                                                                                                                                                             
  // a URL to fetch data from in the prepareData() function.                                                                                                                                                                                 
}

func (rules JSONRules) prepareData() {
  rules.data = JSONData {
    actualValue : "Expected Value",
  }
}

type JSONData struct {
  actualValue string
}

type JSONCondition struct {
  expectedValue string
}

func (condition JSONCondition) Evaluate(data Data) bool {
  if data.actualValue == condition.expectedValue {
    return true
  }

  return false
}
```

Comment: I think the main problem is a conceptual. Who owns the data? Who the rules? what is the difference between a `Rule` and a `Condition`. Your point 2 indicates that getData() always returns the same type of data, otherwise it _cannot_ be abstracted or Data has to conform to a certain interface. I think your point 2 is the main problem in your design: The different rules operate on different data and the only thing in common is that rules can be evaluated. Maybe you could clarify your ideas a bit more?

Comment: Hi @Volker, thanks for the comment. Quite possibly the design might need improvement. I saw some value in decoupling fetching/preparing the data and evaluating the conditions, and I can implement this design in other OOP languages by skipping type checking on the Data only, so I went for that. But most likely in most cases the structure of the data will be tightly coupled with the conditions evaluated upon them, so it might be appropriate to put them together. I'll look into that direction and I'll post if there's anything interesting.